Irreps of Poincare group
I'm looking for some more explanation of the following claims - I have graduate-level "mathematical maturity" (ex. in geometry) but am not a representation theorist.

Recall than an irreducible linear representation $V$ of the Poincare group is described by the following data. First, one restricts to the
abelian subgroup of translations, $T$.
As $T$ is abelian, $V = \oplus V_\chi$ with $\chi \in T^*$ where $V_\chi = \{v \in V: t \cdot v = \chi(t) v \}$
The Lorentz group $G = SO(n-1,1)$ acts on $T^*$
$\{\chi \in T^* : V_\chi \neq 0 \}$ is an orbit $\mathcal{O}$ of $G$.
Let $H$ be the isotropy subgroup of some $\chi_0 \in \mathcal{O}$. Then the restriction of the representation to $H$ defines an irrep of $H$ in $V_{\chi_0}$.
Now the action of $G$ on $\mathcal{O} = G/H$ lifts to an action on the (associated?) vector bundle $E = G \times_H V_{\chi_0} = G \times V_{\chi_0} /H$
There is a natural $G$ action on the space of sections $\Gamma(E)$ and the original representation $V$ is realized as an irrep of $\Gamma(E)$.

Is this the little group method of classifying Poincare irreps seen in physics texts? What is a reference for this argument?

I'd not heard the term "little groups method" before but a cursory search suggests that this is indeed that. It seems to also be found under "Wigner's classification" or "Mackey's Machine" (although the latter might be more for finite groups) so their books on the subject are probably a reasonable place to start.
